# Android recyclerview update item with socket after sort

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, socket.io, adapter

How can update a specific item in Recyclerview without having a position?

I have a list that I fill first through the REST. And then any data that has changed from the server side, I will update it through the socket.

To update, needed a postion of the item. For this, I consider a position for each item by default (static) from the server side, but the problem arises when the user side sorts that list. (just sorted in localy)

After sorting, the positions of the items are messed up, and for this reason, it is no longer possible to update them through the statically defined positions.

How can i do this ?

Thanks for ideas!

Comment: `For this, I consider a position for each item by default (static) from the server side,` Pretty bad design. If you want to update items then do not use items from the recycleview but items from the adapter list. And dont take a position but an item_id or such. When you updated the list. Sort it again if needed and then notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: @blackapps Yes its bad design, but when you want to update specific value of an item without have position, how you can update it? for example if you  want to update a Price value of an item. (From server side i just send price value changed to the clients) I have done this so that the user's resources and internet are consumed less. What is your plan? example i send [[0,1.5],[1,0.6],[2,1.6],[3,1.03]] data to clients for update every prices changed from server. the currently idea is work without any problem, but after do sorting data by user, the problem is come.

Comment: I already told you how you could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it by below function:

```
private int findPosition(int staticPosition) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
            if(dataList.get(i).getPosition() == staticPosition) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Maybe it's bad idea, but working perfectly. You can find position of item in the list after sort or by default.

Full code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    public Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {

            if(getActivity() != null) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        String s = args[0].toString();
                        Type type = new TypeToken< List<List<int>>>(){}.getType();
                        List<List<int>> list  = gson.fromJson(s, type);
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            List<int> single = list.get(i);

                            int staticPostion     = single.get(0);
                            int price          = single.get(1);

                            if(marketAdapter != null) {
                                int postion =  findPosition(staticPostion);
                                dataList.get(postion).setPrice(price);
                                marketAdapter.notifyItemChanged(postion);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
            }

        }
    };
```